# SQL why does dateA - dateB <= '3 years' give a different result than dateA <= dateB + '3 years'

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, case, intervals

I was doing a MODE.com SQL practice question about date format.

The practice question is: Write a query that counts the number of companies acquired within 3 years, 5 years, and 10 years of being founded (in 3 separate columns). Include a column for total companies acquired as well. Group by category and limit to only rows with a founding date.

It uses two tables:

`tutorial.crunchbase_companies_clean_date` table, which includes information about all the companies, like company name, founded year, etc.

`tutorial.crunchbase_acquisitions_clean_date`table, which includes the information about all the acquired companies, like acquired company name, acquired date, etc.

My code is:

```
SELECT companies.category_code,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acq.acquired_at_cleaned - companies.founded_at_clean:: timestamp <= '3 years' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS less_than_3_years,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acq.acquired_at_cleaned - companies.founded_at_clean:: timestamp <= '5 years' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS between_3_to_5_years,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acq.acquired_at_cleaned - companies.founded_at_clean:: timestamp <= '10 years' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS within_10_years,
       COUNT(1) AS total
FROM tutorial.crunchbase_companies_clean_date companies
JOIN tutorial.crunchbase_acquisitions_clean_date acq 
ON companies.permalink = acq.company_permalink
WHERE companies.founded_at_clean IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY total DESC
```

The result is:
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePcUE.png)

The answer query is:

```
SELECT companies.category_code,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acquisitions.acquired_at_cleaned <= companies.founded_at_clean::timestamp + INTERVAL '3 years'
                       THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS acquired_3_yrs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acquisitions.acquired_at_cleaned <= companies.founded_at_clean::timestamp + INTERVAL '5 years'
                       THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS acquired_5_yrs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acquisitions.acquired_at_cleaned <= companies.founded_at_clean::timestamp + INTERVAL '10 years'
                       THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS acquired_10_yrs,
       COUNT(1) AS total
  FROM tutorial.crunchbase_companies_clean_date companies
  JOIN tutorial.crunchbase_acquisitions_clean_date acquisitions
    ON acquisitions.company_permalink = companies.permalink
 WHERE founded_at_clean IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY 5 DESC
```

The result is:
[The answer result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htasr.png)

You can see in the screenshots that the results are very similar, but some numbers are different.

The only difference I can see between my query and the answer is in the COUNT statements, but I don't really see the difference, for example, between: `acq.acquired_at_cleaned - companies.founded_at_clean:: timestamp <= '3 years'` and `acquisitions.acquired_at_cleaned <= companies.founded_at_clean::timestamp + INTERVAL '3 years'`

I tried adding `INTERVAL` in my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT companies.category_code,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acq.acquired_at_cleaned - companies.founded_at_clean:: timestamp <= INTERVAL '3 years' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS less_than_3_years,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acq.acquired_at_cleaned - companies.founded_at_clean:: timestamp <= INTERVAL '5 years' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS between_3_to_5_years,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acq.acquired_at_cleaned - companies.founded_at_clean:: timestamp <= INTERVAL '10 years' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS within_10_years,
       COUNT(1) AS total
```

and remove the `INTERVAL` from the answer query:

```
SELECT companies.category_code,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acquisitions.acquired_at_cleaned <= companies.founded_at_clean::timestamp + '3 years'
                       THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS acquired_3_yrs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acquisitions.acquired_at_cleaned <= companies.founded_at_clean::timestamp + '5 years'
                       THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS acquired_5_yrs,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acquisitions.acquired_at_cleaned <= companies.founded_at_clean::timestamp + '10 years'
                       THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS acquired_10_yrs,
       COUNT(1) AS total
```

But the results are the same.

I tried to know the result of just the difference between the acquired_date and founded_date, to see if the value can be compared with `INTERVAL`. The result is in days, which looks promising to me.
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6BWA.png)

I try to give all the information for your consideration. Hope somebody could help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please don't use links in your question. Update it with all the relevant information, preferably as editable text

Comment: It could be that your database treats `INTERVAL '3 years'` as an interval, but not just `'3 years'`, which then results in some string comparison.  Think about the types of the expressions on each side of the `<=` operator.

Comment: @NickW Thank you for your advice. I edited my question. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: @JonArmstrong I also tried to use interval in my query, or remove the interval from the answer query, but the result is the same. And I also specified timestamp in the comparison, so I don't think it's the string comparison problem.

Comment: A test case would be helpful.  It appears the only difference between the two queries is the "INTERVAL" operation vs the possible string comparison.  Can you include (in the question) the adjustment to your query which used `INTERVAL`?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS (Postgres?), removing one of the repetitive date tags.

Comment: @Parfait I wanted too. But mode.com didn't specify what kind of RDBMS it uses

Comment: @JonArmstrong Thank you for your advice. I added my adjustment with `INTERVAL`

Comment: It turns out that the difference can be compared to an interval, but the value is specified in seconds, which means the logic would need to have detail about the actual number of days (in seconds).  That's why, in the given question, we would simply apply the interval to one of the dates and then compare with the other date.  This avoids the need to know the actual number of days (or seconds) in that particular year.

Comment: @Parfait Though mode.com doesn't specify what kind, but it uses some reference of Postgres

Comment: @JonArmstrong "but the value is specified in seconds", by "values", do you mean the value of the difference? I tried the query `acq.acquired_at_cleaned - companies.founded_at_clean::timestamp AS time_difference` and the result is in days. You can check out in my edited question. Thank you!

Comment: Ignoring which literal units we used for a moment, the real problem is needing use a different _interval_ when translating from `d2 - INTERVAL xxx = d1` to `d2 - d1 = INTERVAL xxx`.  We can't blindly use _INTERVAL '1' YEAR_ without regard to leap year.

Comment: @JonArmstrong I've read your answer again and I think I get your point. Even your query format is worth learning. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to add/subtract the INTERVAL to/from one date/time and then compare with the other date/time. Don't subtract the date/times and then compare to a string literal.  Your database seems to understand `'3 YEARS'` as `3 * 365 days`, regardless of the actual number of days between `someDateTime` and `someDateTime +/- '3 YEARS'`.  The actual number of days from year to year could be 365 or 366, depending on whether a leap year is crossed.

Here's a simple example of comparing with a specific interval, which also requires we know whether and how many leap years were crossed.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=037b2a315b221bef322e73274accce33)

The test case:

```sql
WITH dates AS (
        SELECT '2021-01-01'::date AS xdate
     )
SELECT xdate - (xdate - INTERVAL '1' YEAR) AS diff
     , xdate - (xdate - INTERVAL '1' YEAR) = '1 YEAR'   AS b1
     , xdate - (xdate - INTERVAL '1' YEAR) = '365 DAYS' AS b2
     , xdate - (xdate - INTERVAL '1' YEAR) = '366 DAYS' AS b3
  FROM dates
;

-- AND --

WITH dates AS (
        SELECT '2021-01-01'::date AS xdate
     )
SELECT xdate - (xdate - INTERVAL '1' YEAR) AS diff
     , xdate - (xdate - INTERVAL '1' YEAR) = INTERVAL '1' YEAR   AS b1
     , xdate - (xdate - INTERVAL '1' YEAR) = INTERVAL '365 DAYS' AS b2
     , xdate - (xdate - INTERVAL '1' YEAR) = INTERVAL '366 DAYS' AS b3
  FROM dates
;
```

Result:

| diff | b1 | b2 | b3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 366 days | f | f | t |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=89d63b855c78cfc85dad95c48d02142e)

```sql
WITH dates AS (
        SELECT '2021-01-01'::date AS xdate
     )
   , diff AS (
        SELECT xdate - (xdate - INTERVAL '1' YEAR) AS diff
          FROM dates
     )
SELECT diff
     , CASE WHEN diff = (366*24*60*60 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND)
            THEN 1
        END AS compare1
     , 366*24*60*60 AS seconds
     , CASE WHEN diff = (366*24*60*60 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND)
            THEN 1
        END AS compare2
     , CASE WHEN diff = '31622400 SECONDS'
            THEN 1
        END AS compare3
  FROM diff
;
```

The result:

| diff | compare1 | seconds | compare2 | compare3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 366 days | 1 | 31622400 | 1 | 1 |

Original response:

[The fiddle for PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=321315b464184c580c9193ee757ff262)

The behavior shown here (below) is similar to the posted behavior.

The problem is the value generated isn't necessarily what you think.

Here's a test case in postgresql which might be representative of your issue.

Maybe this is related to `leap year`, where the number of days in a year isn't constant.

So it's probably safer to compare the dates rather than assume some number of days, which is probably the assumption `<= '3 years'` makes.

The test SQL:

```
WITH test (acquired_at_cleaned, founded_at_clean, n) AS (
        SELECT current_date, current_date - INTERVAL '4' YEAR, 4 UNION
        SELECT current_date, current_date - INTERVAL '3' YEAR, 3 UNION
        SELECT current_date, current_date - INTERVAL '2' YEAR, 2 UNION
        SELECT current_date, current_date - INTERVAL '1' YEAR, 1
     )
   , cases AS (
        SELECT test.*
             , CASE WHEN acquired_at_cleaned <= founded_at_clean::timestamp + INTERVAL '3' year
                    THEN 1 ELSE NULL
                END AS acquired_3_yrs_case1
             , CASE WHEN acquired_at_cleaned - founded_at_clean::timestamp <= '3 year'
                    THEN 1 ELSE NULL
                END AS acquired_3_yrs_case2
             , acquired_at_cleaned - founded_at_clean::timestamp AS x1
             , acquired_at_cleaned - (n * INTERVAL '1' YEAR) AS x2
          FROM test
     )
SELECT acquired_at_cleaned AS acquired
     , founded_at_clean    AS founded
     , n
     , acquired_3_yrs_case1 AS case1
     , acquired_3_yrs_case2 AS case2
     , x1, x2
  FROM cases
 ORDER BY founded_at_clean
;
```

The result:

| acquired | founded | n | case1 | case2 | x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-25 | 2017-12-25 00:00:00 | 4 | null | null | 1461 days | 2017-12-26 00:00:00 |
| 2021-12-25 | 2018-12-25 00:00:00 | 3 | 1 | null | 1096 days | 2018-12-26 00:00:00 |
| 2021-12-25 | 2019-12-25 00:00:00 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 731 days | 2019-12-26 00:00:00 |
| 2021-12-25 | 2020-12-25 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 365 days | 2020-12-26 00:00:00 |

Interesting result.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite a noob to SQL and Stackoverflow. Your test SQL is too complex for me to understand now, but I do get your point. May I ask which one do you think should be the correct way to handle the query question, in consideration of `leap year`? And thank you so much for your advice on the question and your answer. Merry Christmas!

Comment: @ericzheng0404 I'll adjust the answer with my suggestion, which is to add/subtract the INTERVAL to/from one date/time and then compare with the other date/time.